# Howto get SharePoint version using object model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

With WSSv2 (SharePoint 2003) you could get the version of SharePoint you were working with

e.g. [SPGloablAdmin.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spglobaladmin.version.aspx) gives you "12.0.0.6219" for [WSSv3 SP1](http://www.mindsharpblogs.com/penny/articles/481.aspx)

However its now obsolete (although still works).

Does anyone know the WSSv3 (SharePoint 2007) equivalent?

You have things like [SPWebService.ContentService.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebservice_properties.aspx) but that version number is just a timestamp and doesn't seem to relate back to build versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPFarm.Local.BuildVersion would probably give you the same result without having to refer to a SPWebService.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

SPWebService.ContentService.Farm.BuildVersion

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.buildversion.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As maxim said, but i included it in a Powershell script http://snipt.org/nLS/