# Determine which edition of SharePoint is Installed?

Tags: .net, moss, sharepoint-2007

What is the most reliable way to determine which version of SharePoint is installed. Whether it is WSS or MOSS. If MOSS, whether it is standard or enterprise.

I want to programmatically detect the exact SharePoint version installed..

PS: I already have posted [this question at SharePoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/determine-which-edition-of-sharepoint-is-installed) but could not find a convincing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `SPFarm.Local.BuildVersion` or `SPWebService.ContentService.Farm.BuildVersion` (from this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281718/howto-get-sharepoint-version-using-object-model)) and to build a lookup table based on this: [How to find the level of SharePoint you are running?](http://www.sharepointdesignerstepbystep.com/Blog/Articles/How%20To%20find%20the%20SharePoint%20version.aspx)

Another option is to read directly from `ConfigDB` database, on `Versions` table; you can find [more information here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/laflour/archive/2009/02/22/sharepoint-tip-16-do-you-know-how-to-get-the-sharepoint-version-programmatically.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

### Registry keys on server

You can look for these within the registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS\InstalledProducts.

```
BEED1F75-C398-4447-AEF1-E66E1F0DF91E: SharePoint Foundation 2010 
1328E89E-7EC8-4F7E-809E-7E945796E511: Search Server Express 2010 
B2C0B444-3914-4ACB-A0B8-7CF50A8F7AA0: SharePoint Server 2010 Standard Trial  
3FDFBCC8-B3E4-4482-91FA-122C6432805C: SharePoint Server 2010 Standard  
88BED06D-8C6B-4E62-AB01-546D6005FE97: SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise Trial
D5595F62-449B-4061-B0B2-0CBAD410BB51: SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise  
BC4C1C97-9013-4033-A0DD-9DC9E6D6C887: Search Server 2010 Trial  
08460AA2-A176-442C-BDCA-26928704D80B: Search Server 2010  
84902853-59F6-4B20-BC7C-DE4F419FEFAD: Project Server 2010 Trial  
ED21638F-97FF-4A65-AD9B-6889B93065E2: Project Server 2010 
926E4E17-087B-47D1-8BD7-91A394BC6196: Office Web Companions 2010
```

### Programmatically

See the article [How To: Detect the Installed SKU of SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff721969.aspx) on MSDN. It has a list of GUIDs for each SKU:

### PowerShell

You can also use the PowerShell command get-spfarm | select Products to output GUIDs for the installed SKUs.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested there, the probably most reliable method is to check for the availability of a feature.
There is no function in the SharePoint API that can tell you if it's WSS, MOSS Standard, or MOSS Enterprise.