# VS2010 Detect whether wss3.0 or MOSS 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Can anyone please tell me how can I detect whether a webpart is running under wss3.0 or MOSS 2007 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean programmatically: Try using `SPFarm.Local.BuildVersion` as described in this [blog post](http://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/mark-jones/2012/04/06/how-to-programmatically-detect-the-version-of-sharepoint-2007-and-2010) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205148/determine-which-edition-of-sharepoint-is-installed).